# Save form data then load data into fancybox so user can preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a form where users submit various fields of data. The form is not in a fancybox ...it loads in the browser. A preview button is available and the preview loads into a fancybox. The form has an autosave feature every three minutes and can also be saved manually by clicking a save button. My problem is if the form hasn't been autosaved and the user hasn't mnaually saved it, then fancybox will show the version prior to the latest changes. I currently have it run through the autosave function, then load the fancybox preview, but it seems the data isn't getting saved before fancybox loads it. The autosave works, manual save works, fancybox works and loads the data, but I need it to save the data, then load it in fancybox.

The autosave function uses ajax to save the data via PHP/MySQL.

Thanks so much for any assistance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preview-article').live('click', (function() {
            autoSave();
    }));

    $("#preview-article").fancybox({
            'width': '75%',
            'height': '75%',
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an API option included with fancybox called OnStart which I was able to add my saveTheForm function. The OnStart option is called right before attempting to load the content. So far, it's working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#preview-article').fancybox({
        'onStart': saveTheForm,
        'width': '80%',
        'height': '80%',
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're previewing your form *before* the save function is called. That's why you see the 'old' form instead. You might wanna try something like this:

```
function preview() {
  //open fancybox
}

function saveAndPreview() { //your preview button will call this function
  //save call
  preview();
}
```

Create a function that saves the form, and only then shows the preview. This way you make sure it's saving before the fancybox is called.

Comment: I tried running my save function prior to fancybox, but fancybox still doesn't load the saved data. If I click my save button to save the form field data, and then click the preview button, fancybox loads the latest changes. But if I include the save function before fancybox, fancybox ignores it.

Comment: My knowledge on the subject is a little low, but isn't possible that the fancybox is running asynchronous and loading before the save call anyway? I'd try putting a simple `alert()` before you call the preview function to be sure that it's really saving before the call.

Comment: Yes, fancybox loads before the save call, which is my problem. If I could load/re-initialize fancybox after the save call, that would be great. Maybe re-load fancybox after each save. I did place an alert and the save is happening, but fancybox still loads the data from prior to the save. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's strange. Have you really tried to remove your fancybox call to outside the `$(document).ready()`? This will bind your code to be executed only one time, when the page is loaded. Doing something like putting it in a function would be able to solve this problem.
Do your auto save function changes the value of your html by using `$.html()` or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, I have it outside the doc ready now on a live click ...not adding or replacing html ...just need to figure out how to load/initialize fancybox after saving but fancybox seems to bind itself to the click of the ID when it loads. I think I may resubmit the question here at SO and see if I can get some more ideas ...stumped right now, but I'm a long way from an expert so its easy to stump me :)